# What does sgmf stand for in `sgmf-scripts`?

Tags: commerce-cloud

What does sgmf stand for in the name of the `sgmf-scripts` tool that is used for creating Storefront Reference Architecture overlay cartridges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it stands for **S**ite **G**enesis **M**obile **F**irst.

I don't have anything to share that would confirm it, but this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/b2c-implement-functional-solution/b2c-customize-store-with-ref-architecture) lays out the following two reference architectures

- SiteGenesis
- Storefront Reference Architecture (SFRA).

And now, with SFRA, the focus/difference with SG is the mobile first design as noted through this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/cc-digital-for-developers/digital-ref-architecture).